# Probability drawing balls out of an urn

Tags: probability

Seven balls are randomly withdrawn from an urn that contains $12$ red, $16$ blue, and $18$ green balls. Find the probability that $3$ red, $2$ blue, and $2$ green balls are withdrawn.

The answer is  $= \dfrac{\binom{12}{3}\binom{16}{2}\binom{18}{2}}{\binom{46}{7}}$

My question concerns the denominator. I thought the denominator was:
$\binom{46}{3}\binom{43}{2}\binom{41}{2}$. This is not the same. Could someone explain when the denominator is used where the entire group, $7$ is chosen, vs choosing them in parts like I did, $3, 2, 2$. I have seen it done both ways for different problems but I am not sure which scenario is used when. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The denominator is the expression for the total number of possible outcomes. In this case, to find the total number of outcomes we simply count in how many ways we can choose any $7$ balls from the total $46$ balls. Could you mention the intuition behind what you've done? It seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that in addition to the colors, we put numbers $1$ through $46$ on the balls.
This does not affect the probability of drawing the colors described in the question, but it lets us more easily identify the different ways those colors can be drawn.

Your denominator could occur as follows:

First we choose three balls from the $46$ balls in the urn.
For example, we might choose balls $\{3,15,42\}.$

There are now $43$ balls left in the urn. We choose two balls from these $43.$
For example, if we already chose $\{3,15,42\},$ we might choose balls $\{18,22\}$.

There are now $41$ balls left in the urn. We choose two balls from these $41.$
For example, if we have already drawn the five balls already listed in these examples, we might choose balls $\{4,37\}.$

Note that according to this way of thinking, it matters which order the seven balls $3,4,15,18,22,37,42$ are drawn.
If the first three drawn are $\{18,22,37\},$ that's a different draw.
Your denominator is much larger than $\binom{46}{7}$ because you count many different possible ways in which the each subset of seven balls can be drawn as one group of three and two groups of two (one group later than the other).

It turns out your denominator is correct if the objective is that the *first three* balls must be red, the *next two* must be blue, and the *last two* must be green.
In that case it is not enough to know which subset of seven balls out of the $46$ was drawn, it is also important to know which were the first three and which were the next two so that you can check that the red balls were indeed the first three drawn, and so forth.

But the generally-accepted interpretation of "$3$ red, $2$ blue, and $2$ green balls are withdrawn" is that the order in which those balls were drawn doesn't matter, only that any three of them are red, any two are blue, and any two are green.
That's why we choose a denominator that does not make any special distinction about which three balls were drawn first; all we care is at the end, which $7$ balls were drawn from the $46$ in the urn.

Comment: Thanks! You made that very clear.